# Upgrading a package marked as hold, marks it as install in dpkg --get-selections

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

If I mark a package as `hold` with `echo "xyz hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections` and afterwards explicitly use `apt upgrade xyz=1.2.3` the package is marked as `install` in `dpkg --get-selections`.

Is there any way to "permanently" mark a package as `hold`? - I want to update it, but always manually and never as part of another update.

I tried to look online, but there's 100 posts that teaches you how to hold a package, I know that. I also tried `man apt` which sends you to `man apt-get 8` but `upgrade` doesn't really specify anything about `hold`-packages (or suddenly unholding them..) - so I'm also happy if you can provide resources about the behaviour.

---

It kind of tripped me a little when I upgraded 3 packages in a row, to a specific "not-latest" version, and .. the last one got the specified version, but the others were suddenly "latest."

I can see in the output that `apt upgrade` did show me that it was also going to upgrade the other packages.. I just don't want to write a new script like..

```
upgrade(){
  apt-get upgrade $1=$2
  echo "$1 hold" | dpkg --set-selection
}
```

..... or is that the solution I'm looking for?

---

*This question was originally posted on "askubuntu," but since it didn't get any traffic they suggested that I deleted the question and posted it here.*

A user did suggest using `apt-mark`. But it does not solve my problem it just simplifies holding packages.

Comment: FYI, you can use `apt-mark hold packagename(s)` these days. The pipe to `dpkg --set-selection` method still works but is long obsolete. And, no, that won't solve your problem - upgrading a package will **always** clear its hold status, so you have to hold it again. I have several packages that I never want to be auto-upgraded, so I have several commands like the following in root's history: `apt-get install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64; apt-mark hold linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64`. I haven't written a function/script for it, it's never been a big enough problem to bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a way to do this with package holds; but there is a different way of preventing upgrades: you can pin a package with priority -1. Create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` containing

```
Package: xyz
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

`xyz` will then never be a candidate for upgrades, unless a specific version is requested.

Comment: Thank you! This looks exactly like what I'm looking for 